# PandocRuby: set default options (so they will be used whenever I call #convert)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pandoc

I'm using PandocRuby to generate HTML and docx from the same source.

So far, I simply used `PandocRuby.convert` two times with quite independent options. But now I want to introduce options (`f: 'markdown-raw_html'`) that need to be applied to both calls, so instead of copy&pasting and creating smelly code, I'd love to set this option somewhere globally.

```
# config/initializers/pandoc.rb
PANDOC_OPTIONS = {f: 'markdown-raw_html'}

# In my controller, rendering HTML
pandoc_options = PANDOC_OPTIONS.merge(
                   to: :html
                 )

render plain: PandocRuby.convert(report_content, :s, pandoc_options)

# In my controller, rendering docx
pandoc_options = PANDOC_OPTIONS.merge(
                   to: :docx,
                   'toc-depth' => 2
                 ).compact
send_report(PandocRuby.convert(report_content, :toc, pandoc_options), @report, :docx)
```

But I'm unsure how to do that. My dirty workaround at the moment is to create a global variable `PANDOC_OPTIONS` and merging it with the additional options of each call, but that's very smelly (and prone to be forgotten somewhere else).

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: you may want to use a helper function? e.g. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

Comment: Usually I'd suggest to put this into a [defaults file](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#default-files). Are default files supported by PandocRuby?